# remove slider from scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I try to write software for smartphone phonegap + html5 + jquerymobile
Confronted with the problem

I need to put on one page two list, so that they were independent, ie each with their own scrolls.
That I got http://jsfiddle.net/nalsur/skqmy/1/

But it looks like it's frankly not much: (
I would like to leave the current functionality but to remove the slider, so that would be between the two lists did not have any items

Is this possible?

Thank you

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - try using only `overflow:auto;` and remove `overflow:scroll;`. This means that the scrollbars will be displayed only when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly. I no need slider in any case. I need only functionality of scrollbar, but without slider

Comment: Ah, you want to be able to touch scroll on your phone without showing a scrollbar? Thing is if I create a site with scrollable divs, those scrollbars aren't showing on my smart phone, but I can still scroll. It's up the the smart phone browser to decide how to display them (if at all).

Comment: Yes, this is what i need:) I can't check it on smart phone, but very hope that you are right, and my problem will solve automatically:) Thanks